# Validation loses ajax form changes

Tags: 7, forms, ajax

I have a custom form. On an element on the form I have an ajax callback:

```
  $form['test'] = array(
    '#type' => 'textfield',
    '#title' => t('test'),
    '#ajax' => array(
      'callback' => 'test_ajax',
      'wrapper' => 'rainbow',
      'method' => 'replace',
      'effect' => 'fade',
    ),
    '#prefix' => '<div id="rainbow">',
    '#suffix' => '</div>',
  );
```

My callback function is:

```
function test_ajax($form, $form_state) {
  $form['test']['#suffix'] = '<h1>Test</h1></div>';
  return $form['test'];
}
```

When the ajax event is triggered Test is added to the element as a suffix.

If I then press enter to submit the form and a validation error occurs the suffix reverts back to the original value meaning I lose my message.

Looking in my custom validate function I can see that the `$form` object has the original suffix. Editing the suffix here makes no difference to the display.

I have also tried adding the following to my validate function.

```
  $form_state['rebuild'] = TRUE;
  $form_state['flag'] = 1;
```

However the original suffix is still displayed.

**How can I get modified suffix to remain?**